# How to find a scaling expert?

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-applications, sql-server, scalability

The web application is in ASP.NET and Sql Server and is growing much faster than anticipated.

Where can I find an expert who has previously had experience of going from a small website to solution used daily by thousands?  Someone who can review our system and give us advice on performance improvements and updating our coding practices.

Comment: When you're interviewing for experts, choose the one who keeps changing size :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are in the **Microsoft** technologies, I would like to tell you they have [**Microsoft Innovation Centers**](http://www.microsoft.com/mic) all around the world filled with guys paid to help you.

I had the chance to ask the exact same question as you regarding SQL Server about an application I worked on that was generating millions records.

The local [**Microsoft Evangelist**](http://be.linkedin.com/in/dhernie) explained me in less than 15 minutes all I needed to know to solve my problem. So I learn about [memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067.aspx) & cpu instances, [SAN integration](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/SAN-considerations-for-your-SQL-Server-environment), etc.

They will eventually redirect you to a [**local partner**](https://partner.microsoft.com) that is there to help you as well.

Comment: On Microsoft Innovation Centers page - they list 90+ centers around the world.  But none are in US.

Comment: Ask your local evangelist, there are a lot in USA.